# Should format a new 20TB hard drive as Mac OS Extended or APFS for better data recovery chances in the future?

Tags: hard-drive, recovery, disk-format

I have a Macbook and bought an internal 20TB hard drive that I am using through a docking station. I am wondering if I should format the drive as Mac OS Extended or APFS, if for example one day the drive stops working and I need to contact a data recovery service? Which would lead to better recovery? Thanks

Comment: Your best chances for data recovery is to ***make a backup.***  Full stop.

Comment: A backup of twenty TB needs more than twenty TB to hold it.  But if you can get by with ten TB, I'd say make it a RAID.

Comment: @WGroleau RAID is not backup.

Comment: RAID is not backup.  But if you don't have a drive big enough to do a backup, RAID is better than nothing.

Comment: @WGroleau a 20 TB drive needs at least a 20 TB drive as a backup target. Using RAID instead of backups gives a false sense of security. Anyway, how would you turn **a single** 20 TB drive into a  Redundant AID?

Comment: A _second_ 20TB is enough for the _first_ backup of 20TB.  Then there's no room for changes.  I don't recommend RAID as backup.  I recommend it if you for some reason cannot do a regular backup. It's a last resort, and not immune to all failures.  But a single-drive RAID does allow recovery if bad sectors occur.  RAID is better on more than one drive but can be done with two or more copies of everything in different parts of the drive.

Comment: Don't you mean an EXTERNAL drive? It's outside the MBP, right? But, as everyone says: you need a second copy (at least) on a separate device. You don't *want* to contact a data recovery service.

Answer (score 6):

My *opinion* is that:

1. APFS is more robust than HFS+ and so less likely to become corrupted in the event of unexpected disconnection or system crash.
2. HFS+ is better documented and understood by recovery services and so has greater chance of recovery if you do get corruption.

Backup is your best protection. It is cheaper than a recovery service.

Comment: Too bad I can only up vote once.  A backup protects against a physical failure; regardless of a filesystem choice.